# How can I creat a sails.js project with coffee script and ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, sails.js, ecmascript-6

I try to create sails.js project with coffee script and ES6
First, I use sails new 'appName'
and 
npm install coffee-script --save 
npm install babel --save

and modify app.js

```
options = {
  loose     : "all",
  stage     : 1,
  ignore    : null,
  only      : null,
  extensions: null
};
require("sails-hook-babel/node_modules/babel/register")(options);
```

but it's something wrong

I see others can create it by auto(It can creat app.coffee local.coffee...etc don't need to modify)
How to do this?

```
-----------------------------------------------
error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
error:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning: Task "watch" not found.

Aborted due to warnings.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.

error: Troubleshooting tips:
error:
error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
error:
error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
error:
error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
error:      e.g., `/Users/yangjunzhang/Documents/workspace/burstWork/.tmp` ?
error:
error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
error:      sudo chown -R 501 /Users/yangjunzhang/Documents/workspace/burstWork/.tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `babel` package as standalone package but not from `sails-hook-babel`. My integrating flow looks like this:

1) Install `babel-cli` and `babel-preset-es2015`:

```
npm install --save babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

2) Change your `package.json` file, `scripts` section with following script:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "babel-node --presets es2015 app.js"
}
```

3) Start your application with `npm start` script:

```
npm start
```

Afterwards, you can write all your code with ES6 syntax and use `npm start` for start the project.